# Power Automate Flow is not showing up to add it to a Solution

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps, power-automate, dataverse, ms-forms

I have created a Automated Power Automate Flow to send a Customer Voice Survey when an opportunity is modified.

I added Customer Voice trigger in the Flow.

I'm trying to add it to a solution but it is not showing up in the Flows List while adding.

Can anyone help me in this issue.

Comment: Are they in the same environment - please check from the top right corner?

Comment: Yes. They are in the same environment.

Comment: So if they try in the same environment to add first include Connection references if you have one to Solution. Ones when you added it you can try again to add whole flow.